# Stars in Google Maps reappear X days after removing them

Tags: google-maps

I'm using the "Starred places" feature in Google Maps on my iPhone: namely, when you select a place, you can hit the "Save" bookmark icon, and then add it to "Starred places".

I've added the star to many places and things work great. The issue is when I try to *remove* a star...

I find that if I try to remove a star, it'll remove it and everything looks correct, but after a few days it'll come back as though I never removed the star.

Any suggestions for how to ensure that it'll stay removed?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug on the iOS client, and I'm not sure how long you need to wait to see the stars come back. However, I was able to figure out a solution, and the way I verified it works is by doing the following:

1. Remove a star via Google Maps iOS app.
2. Remove a star via Google Maps on mobile Safari.
3. Come back X days later (in this case 10 days).

I then noticed that #1 came back (i.e. the bug in question), but #2 did not come back, meaning a good workaround is to remove the star from mobile Safari.

It's also unclear to me if it's only "Starred places" that has this issue or any of the other labels (e.g. "Want to go", "Favorites", custom lists, etc.) have similar issues.